# C++: Issue with lambda function and capture list

Tags: c++, lambda

I have the following function:

```
double mn = 2.0;
double mx = 5.0;
auto isBetween = [&,mx,mn](double y) -> bool{
    if (mn<y<mx) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

However, when I debug, all of the values I pass as `double y` return true.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: `mn<y<mx` -> `mn<y && y<mx`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test `if (mn<y<mx)` isn't what you want.

You want something like: `if (mn < y && y < mx)` instead.

Comment: Wow... that was easy.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the `<` operator cannot be chained the way it can in mathematics. In the expression `(mn < y < mx)`, `(mn < y)` evaluates to either 1 (true) or 0 (false), and from there the expression is equivalent to `1 < mx` or `0 < mx`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is here `(mn<y<mx)`, which can be read as

```
(mn < y) < mx
```

This means, that first `mn < y` is evaluated, which leads in a result of type `bool` and is either `ture` or `false`. The result is finally compared to `mx`.

What you tried to do is to check, if `mn < y` **and** `y < mx`, what has to be expressed like this:

```
if (mn<y && y<mx)
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue.